# Return most recent non-null value prior to date minus 1 year -- Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table with ID, Date, Value. For each row, I want to return the most recent non-null value where Date <= Date minus 1 year.

I'm trying variations of window functions with last_value or lag, and partitioning on ID, order by Date, with the IGNORE NULLS clause. However, I'm not sure where to include the condition where Date <= Date minus 1 year

Sample Data:

| ID | Date | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01-Jan-19 | NULL |
| 1 | 02-Jan-19 | NULL |
| 1 | 03-Jan-19 | NULL |
| 1 | 04-Jan-19 | NULL |
| 1 | 05-Jan-19 | NULL |
| 1 | 01-Jan-20 | NULL |
| 1 | 02-Jan-20 | 20 |
| 1 | 03-Jan-20 | NULL |
| 1 | 04-Jan-20 | NULL |
| 1 | 05-Jan-20 | 30 |
| 1 | 01-Jan-21 | 20 |
| 1 | 02-Jan-21 | NULL |
| 1 | 03-Jan-21 | NULL |
| 1 | 04-Jan-21 | NULL |
| 1 | 05-Jan-21 | 30 |
| 2 | 01-Jan-19 | NULL |
| 2 | 02-Jan-19 | NULL |
| 2 | 03-Jan-19 | NULL |
| 2 | 04-Jan-19 | 30 |
| 2 | 05-Jan-19 | 30 |
| 2 | 01-Jan-20 | 25 |
| 2 | 02-Jan-20 | 20 |
| 2 | 03-Jan-20 | NULL |
| 2 | 04-Jan-20 | NULL |
| 2 | 05-Jan-20 | 30 |
| 2 | 01-Jan-21 | 20 |
| 2 | 02-Jan-21 | 15 |
| 2 | 03-Jan-21 | 15 |
| 2 | 04-Jan-21 | 15 |
| 2 | 05-Jan-21 | 30 |

Desired Results:

| ID | Date | Value | Most_Recent_Prior_Year_Date | Most_Recent_Prior_Year_Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01-Jan-19 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 1 | 02-Jan-19 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 1 | 03-Jan-19 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 1 | 04-Jan-19 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 1 | 05-Jan-19 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 1 | 01-Jan-20 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 1 | 02-Jan-20 | 20 | NULL | NULL |
| 1 | 03-Jan-20 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 1 | 04-Jan-20 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 1 | 05-Jan-20 | 30 | NULL | NULL |
| 1 | 01-Jan-21 | 20 | NULL | NULL |
| 1 | 02-Jan-21 | NULL | 02-Jan-20 | 20 |
| 1 | 03-Jan-21 | NULL | 02-Jan-20 | 20 |
| 1 | 04-Jan-21 | NULL | 02-Jan-20 | 20 |
| 1 | 05-Jan-21 | 30 | 05-Jan-20 | 30 |
| 2 | 01-Jan-19 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 2 | 02-Jan-19 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 2 | 03-Jan-19 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 2 | 04-Jan-19 | 30 | NULL | NULL |
| 2 | 05-Jan-19 | 30 | NULL | NULL |
| 2 | 01-Jan-20 | 25 | NULL | NULL |
| 2 | 02-Jan-20 | 20 | NULL | NULL |
| 2 | 03-Jan-20 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 2 | 04-Jan-20 | NULL | 04-Jan-19 | 30 |
| 2 | 05-Jan-20 | 30 | 05-Jan-19 | 30 |
| 2 | 01-Jan-21 | 20 | 01-Jan-20 | 25 |
| 2 | 02-Jan-21 | 15 | 02-Jan-20 | 20 |
| 2 | 03-Jan-21 | 15 | 02-Jan-20 | 20 |
| 2 | 04-Jan-21 | 15 | 02-Jan-20 | 20 |
| 2 | 05-Jan-21 | 30 | 05-Jan-20 | 30 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF you strickly have only one row per day per id then you can use:

A single LEFT JOIN and WHERE/QUALIFY will work here:

```
SELECT 
    a.ID,
    a.Date,
    a.Value
    b.Data AS Most_Recent_Prior_Year_Date
    b.Value AS Most_Recent_Prior_Year_Value
FROM table AS a
LEFT JOIN table AS b 
    on a.id = b.id AND DATEADD('year',-1,a.date) >= b.date
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY a.id, a.date ORDER BY b.date DESC NULLS LAST) = 1
```

Otherwise you will want to first separate out a single value per day aka MAX, MIN, FIRST_VALE and then run the above over that output.

Comment: Thanks, this ended up working perfectly for me!

Answer (score 0):

Consider `group by` and two `join`s instead of window functions, e.g.

```
select Id, Date, Value
from DataTable d1
inner join (
    select Id, Date as Most_Recent_Prior_Year_Date, max(Value) as Most_Recent_Prior_Year_Value 
    -- max(Value) because there could be many values for that day
    from DataTable d3
    inner join (
        select Id, max(Date) as MostRecentDate
        from DataTable
        where Date <= DATEADD(year, -1, CURRENT_DATE())
        group by Id
    ) d4 on d3.Id = d4.Id AND d3.Date = d4.MostRecentDate
    group by Id, Date
) d2 on d1.Id = d2.Id
```